# Replacing a word with another word, and replacing an image with another image in a PDF file through python, is this possible?

Tags: python, image, pdf, text

I need to replace a K words with K other words for every PDF file I have within a certain path file location and on top of this I need to replace every logo with another logo. I have around 1000 PDF files, and so I do not want to use Adobe Acrobat and edit 1 file at a time. How can I start this?

Replacing words seems at least doable as long as there is a decent PDF reader one can access through Python ( Note I want to do this task in Python ), however replacing an image might be more difficult. I will most likely have to find the dimension of the current image and resize the image being used to replace the current image dynamically, whilst the program runs through these PDF files.

Hi, so I've written down some code regarding this:

```
from pikepdf import Pdf, PdfImage, Name
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
import zlib

example = Pdf.open(r'...\Likelihood.pdf')
PagesWithImages = []
ImageCodesForPages = []  

# Grab all the pages and all the images in every page. 
for i in example.pages:
    if len(list(i.images.keys())) >= 1:
        PagesWithImages.append(i)
        ImageCodesForPages.append(list(i.images.keys()))

pdfImages = [] 

for i,j in zip(PagesWithImages, ImageCodesForPages):
    for x in j: 
        pdfImages.append(i.images[x])


# Replace every single page using random image, ensure that the dimensions remain the same?
for i in pdfImages:
    pdfimage = PdfImage(i)
    rawimage = pdfimage.obj
    im = Image.open(r'...\panda.jpg')
    pillowimage = pdfimage.as_pil_image()
    print(pillowimage.height)
    print(pillowimage.width)
    im = im.resize((pillowimage.width, pillowimage.height))
    im.show()
    rawimage.write(zlib.compress(im.tobytes()), filter=Name("/FlateDecode"))
    rawimage.ColorSpace = Name("/DeviceRGB")
```

So just one problem, it doesn't actually replace anything. If you're wondering why and how I wrote this code I actually got it from this documentation:

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pikepdf/latest/pikepdf.pdf

Start at Page 53

I essentially put all the pdfImages into a list, as 1 page can have multiple images. In conjunction with this, the last for loop essentially tries to replace all these images whilst maintaining the same width and height size. Also note, the file path names I changed here and it definitely is not the issue.

Again Thank You

Comment: Oops! You seem to have forgotten to post the code you're struggling with

Comment: It's much more complex than you think....But, You can try this in easy way...1)Don't try to replace the image. Simply create a new PDF & insert `image` (Explore FPDF library) that you want to replace `first` . & Then  'copy text `from old `PDF` into a `str` var & do whatever replacement operations uisng python. Print same `str` into `New pdf` that you already has replaced image.

Comment: You cannot replace words or images without rebuilding the PDF. It is a binary file not some text file.

Comment: Everyone, check out the solution I have posted. Let me know what you guys think of it!

Comment: @Steveit - you wrote in the title: "Replacing a word with another word". I am looking for a way to replace text in PDF. Could not find this in your code. Can you post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong. So for anyone that wants to actually replace an image with another image in place on a PDF file what you do is:

```
from pikepdf import Pdf, PdfImage, Name
from PIL import Image
import zlib

example = Pdf.open(filepath, allow_overwriting_input=True)
PagesWithImages = []
ImageCodesForPages = []  

# Grab all the pages and all the images in every page. 
for i in example.pages:
    imagelists = list(i.images.keys())
    if len(imagelists) >= 1:
        for x in imagelists:
            rawimage = i.images[x]
            pdfimage = PdfImage(rawimage)
            rawimage = pdfimage.obj 
            pillowimage = pdfimage.as_pil_image()
            im = Image.open(imagePath)
            im = im.resize((pillowimage.width, pillowimage.height))
            rawimage.write(zlib.compress(im.tobytes()), filter=Name("/FlateDecode"))
            rawimage.ColorSpace = Name("/DeviceRGB")
            rawimage.Width, rawimage.Height = pillowimage.width, pillowimage.height

example.save()
```

Essentially, I changed the arguments in the first line, such that I specify that I can overwrite. In conjunction, I also added the last line which actually allows me to save.